# Validation Excel before export to Access

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

Hey I have written a code that validate all the row of an excel sheet before nut I miss some points. Here is the code

```
Sub Validation_Trades()

Dim varTxt As String
Dim errTxt As String
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim c As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("Trades")
c = 2

Do

varTxt = WS.Range("A" & CStr(c)).Value
errTxt = WS.Range("AP" & CStr(c)).Value

If varTxt = "" Then Exit Do

If Cells(c, 3) = "" Then errTxt = "Missing Ticket Number"
If Cells(c, 4) = "" Then errTxt = "Missing BRKR1"
If Cells(c, 5) = "" Then errTxt = "Missing BRKR2"
If Cells(c, 6) = "" Then errTxt = "Missing Trade Date"
If Cells(c, 7) = "" Then errTxt = "Missing Rec Time"
If Cells(c, 8).Value < Cells(c, 7).Value Then errTxt = "Wrong Sent Time"
If Cells(c, 9) = "" Then errTxt = "Missing Exec Time"
If Cells(c, 10) = "" Then errTxt = "Missing Cust Short Code"
If Cells(c, 12) = "" Then errTxt = "Missing Trader Initial"


c = c + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

1. At the end of every IF, If it is true I want to exit something like `If Cells(c, 3) = "" Then errTxt = "Missing Ticket Number" Then Exit Do`  but 2 times Then doesn't work
2. At the end if there is NO ERROR, set errTxt as "Processed"
3. I want to test `If Cells(c, 13) <> Or("Y","N","") Then errTxt = "Wrong OATS"` but the OR statement doesn't have the good syntax

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

```
 If Cells(c, 3) = "" Then 
    errTxt = "Missing Ticket Number"
    Exit Do
 End If
```

2.

```
 If varTxt = "" Then
    errTxt = "Processed"
    Exit Do
 End If
```

3.

```
Cells(c, 13) <> "Y" And Cells(c, 13) <> "N" And Cells(c, 13) <> "")
```